# Prove that the function is a surjection

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives, functional-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable nonconstant function with $f(f(x))=f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that the range of the fucntion is all of $\mathbb{R}$.

All that I have gotten is for all $x$, either $f'(x)=0$ or $f'(f(x))=1$ should hold. Also that for all $x$ in the range of $f$, $f(x)=x$. Proving that the function is unbounded would do it. How do I proceed from here ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you've got the right statement, because a constant function $x \mapsto c$ on $\mathbb{R}$ will satisfy the hypothesis, but the range will not be all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MathsMatador Sorry, I forgot to mention that the function was nonconstant.